# perl's $-[0] produces unexpected results for non-ASCII data

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

Consider the following input data in file `y.txt` (encoded in UTF-8).

```
bar
föbar
```

and a file `y.pl`, which puts the two input lines into an array and processes them, looking for substring start positions.

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my @array;

while (<>) {
  push @array, $_;
  print $-[0] . "\n" if /bar/;
}

# $array[0] = "bar", $array[1] = "föbar"
print $-[0] . "\n" if $array[1] =~ /$array[0]/u;
```

If I call `perl y.pl < y.txt`,  I get

```
0
2
3
```

as the output.  However, I would expect that the last number is 2 also, but for some reason the second `/.../` regexp behaves differently.  What am I missing?  I guess it's an encoding issue, but whatever I tried, I didn't succeed.  This is Perl 5.18.2.

Comment: On Perl 5.22.2 under Cygwin it works for me.

Comment: Works on Perl 5.20.1 on x86_64-linux (CentOS 6)

Comment: Works fine under v5.22.1 [Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS]

Comment: Thanks for testing.  So it seems to be a bug in 5.18.2...  Bad...  Any ideas how to circumvent the problem elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in 5.18.

```
$ 5.18.2t/bin/perl a.pl a
0
2
3

$ 5.20.1t/bin/perl a.pl a
0
2
2
```

I can't find a workaround. Adding `utf8::downgrade($array[0]);` or `utf8::downgrade($array[0], 1);` works in the case you presented, but not using the following data or any other where the interpolated pattern contains characters >255.

```
♠bar
f♠♠bar
```

It appears that this can only be fixed by upgrading your Perl, which is actually quite simple. (Just make sure to install it to a different directory than your system `perl` by following the instructions in `INSTALL`!)